# Loading an extension's popup.html from another extension

Tags: google-chrome-extension, opera-extension

Opera recently announce their sidebar extensions.
In their boilerplate they load a URL into an iframe, similar to this:
http://julip.co/2010/01/how-to-build-a-chrome-extension-part-3-loading-any-web-page-in-a-popup/

I aim to make a universal wrapper extension for loading other installed extensions to the sidebar and I tried loading a "chrome-extension://" url to the iframe but it didn't work (Got a "This webpage is not available" page instead).

```
iframe.src = "chrome-extension://ggfngijafepjalmbhefafhdeedobcdbf/popup.html";
```

I got a feeling its due to security restrictions but does anyone know of other ways to load another extension's popup in another extension's popup?

Or theres no way at all?

Answer (score 0):

Unless the extension specifically allows to load its files in [`"web_accessible_resources"`](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/manifest/web_accessible_resources), you can't access them.

Even if you did, you probably break lots of assumptions that extensions have; it's not a good idea.

Comment: Ok, thanks for the explanation.
Looks like I can shaft this idea away already.